# how to access the value entered in text field in to an object and push to array

Tags: arrays, angularjs

here is my array

```
$scope.dataList = [{name:'lin',dept:'b'},{name:'test',dept:'aaa'}];
```

here is my html code

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in dataList">
                        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="data.isDelete"/>{{$index}}</td>    
                        <td> <input type="text" id="firstName" ng-model="data.name"/></td>    
                        <td><input type="text" id="lastName" ng-model="data.dept"/></td>
                        <td><button ng-click="save()" ng-disabled=""> save row </button></td>

                    </tr>
```

here is my app.js code

```
$scope.save=function(){

            $scope.dataEntered={
                name:document.getElementById("firstName").value,
                dept:document.getElementById("lastName").value
            }
            $scope.dataList.push($scope.dataEntered );
            console.log($scope.dataList);
        };
```

once my object is pushed each time i am getting an repeted row of {name:'lin',dept:'b'} this my problem

my requirement is to create a table with a addRow and deleteRow and saveRow buttons. i am able to add and delete a row. but i am not able to save my data which i have entered and also after clicking save button i have to make it disable the row which i saved.

Comment: So you need to update existing rows, add new rows and delete rows from the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html:

...

```
 <td><button ng-click="save(data)"> save row </button></td>
```

app.js:

```
$scope.save=function(data){

        $scope.dataList.push({name: data.name, dept: data.dept});
        console.log($scope.dataList);
    };
```